# Using a conditional clause in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel like this. I want a new column that selectively takes the 1st value, then the 4th value, then 8th value, then 12th, 15th,19th i.e. the 3rd value once and 4th values every two times. What type of conditional clause should i use. A little hint would be appreciated.

```
A                B
0.3              0.3
1.1              2.6
2.0              4.7
2.6              13.5
2.7              17.4
2.8              22.1
3.6
4.7
5.4
9.7
12.0
13.5
15.9
17.2
17.4
18.7
19.4
20.4
22.1
23.4
27.1
28.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(A:A,IF(ROW(A1)=1,1,4*(MOD(ROW(A1)+1,3)+1)+(ROW(A1)-(MOD(ROW(A1)+1,3)+2))/3*11))
```

You could also do this with an offset formula as pnuts suggested.  I choose to use index to avoid the volatile nature of offset.  If you were doing this for a small data set there is nothing wrong with using offset.

Place the formula above in C1 and copy down.

[image: Proof of Concept]